# QtableView Delete selected file from Sql database

Tags: mysql, sql, qt, qt5, qtableview

Hello guys as i am new in Qt,my problem is i want to delete the already stored images from Sql database for that i have created a delete button in my Gui, it should be like if i press the seleted file in table view should delete from database as well as disapear from tableview. For that i tried my best to make it work but it is not working. Please help.

**// Database.h ///**
i have defined removedRecord

```
public slots:
    bool insertIntoTable(const QVariantList &data);
    bool insertIntoTable(const QString &name, const QByteArray &pic);
    bool removeRecord(const int id);
```

//Database.cpp //

```
**#include "database.h"**

DataBase::DataBase(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

DataBase::~DataBase()
{

}

void DataBase::connectToDataBase()
{
    if(!QFile("../AIC_Data_Base/" DATABASE_NAME).exists()){
        this->restoreDataBase();
    } else {
        this->openDataBase();
    }
}

bool DataBase::restoreDataBase()
{
    if(this->openDataBase()){
        return (this->createTable()) ? true : false;
    } else {
        qDebug() << "Data Base error";
        return false;
    }
    return false;
}

bool DataBase::openDataBase()
{
    db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    db.setHostName(DATABASE_HOSTNAME);
    db.setDatabaseName("../AIC_Data_Base/" DATABASE_NAME);
    if(db.open()){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

void DataBase::closeDataBase()
{
    db.close();
}

bool DataBase::createTable()
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    if(!query.exec( "CREATE TABLE " TABLE " ("
                            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                            TABLE_NAME     " VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL,"
                            TABLE_PIC      " BLOB            NOT NULL"
                        " )"
                    )){
        qDebug() << "DataBase: error of create " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool DataBase::insertIntoTable(const QVariantList &data)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("INSERT INTO " TABLE " ( " TABLE_NAME ", "
                                             TABLE_PIC " ) "
                  "VALUES (:Name, :Pic)");
    query.bindValue(":Name",        data[0].toString());
    query.bindValue(":Pic",         data[1].toByteArray());

    if(!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "error insert info " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool DataBase::insertIntoTable(const QString &name, const QByteArray &pic)
{
    QVariantList data;
    data.append(name);
    data.append(pic);

    if(insertIntoTable(data))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}


bool DataBase::removeRecord(const int id)
{
    QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("DELETE FROM " TABLE " WHERE id= :ID ;");
    query.bindValue(":ID", id);
    if(!query.exec()){
        qDebug() << "error delete row " << TABLE;
        qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Mainwindow.h**

```
private slots:
    void on_pushButton_add_clicked();

    void on_screenButton_clicked();

    void slotCurrentPic(QModelIndex index);

    void on_Delete_Button_clicked(QModelIndex index);
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDesktopWidget>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QString>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QDir>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QBuffer>




MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // this command is used for : setting the title screen and logo.
    this->setWindowTitle("AIC Tool V1.0");
    setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/9982-200.png"));


    db = new DataBase();
    db->connectToDataBase();

    this->setupModel(TABLE,
                     QStringList() << trUtf8("id")
                                   << trUtf8("Picture List")
                                   << trUtf8("Data_Base")
                     );

    this->createUI();




}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_add_clicked()
{

  QFileDialog dialog(this);
  dialog.setNameFilter(tr("*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm"));
  dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
  QString fileName =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"),"../AIC_Incoming_Images",tr ("Image Files(*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm)"));
  ui->label->setText(fileName);

  if(!fileName.isEmpty())
  {

      QImage image(fileName);
         int w = ui->label_newpic->width();
         int h = ui->label_newpic->height();


      QPixmap tasveer =QPixmap::fromImage(image);
      ui->label_newpic->setPixmap(tasveer.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
      //ui->label_datapic->setPixmap(tasveer.scaled(w,h,Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
  }

 else   {

      QMessageBox::critical(this, "Error", "No file selected");
  }
}


void MainWindow::setupModel(const QString &tableName, const QStringList &headers)
{
    model = new QSqlTableModel(this);
    model->setTable(tableName);

    /* Set the columns names in a table with sorted data
     * */
    for(int i = 0, j = 0; i < model->columnCount(); i++, j++){
        model->setHeaderData(i,Qt::Horizontal,headers[j]);
    }
}

void MainWindow::createUI()
{
    ui->tableView->setModel(model);
    ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(0, true);    // Hide the column id Records
    ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(2, true);    // Hide the column with image
    ui->tableView->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    ui->tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    ui->tableView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);  // editing is not allowed
    ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);     // Stretch the last column of around tableView

    /* Connect the signal to change the selection of the current row in the table
     * to the slot to set the image picLabel
     * */
    connect(ui->tableView->selectionModel(), SIGNAL(currentRowChanged(QModelIndex,QModelIndex)),
            this, SLOT(slotCurrentPic(QModelIndex)));

    model->select();
}

void MainWindow::on_screenButton_clicked()
{


    QFileDialog dialog(this);
    dialog.setNameFilter(tr("*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm"));
    dialog.setFileMode(QFileDialog::ExistingFiles);
    dialog.setViewMode(QFileDialog::Detail);
    //QPixmap inPixmap =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"),"../AIC_Incoming_Images",tr ("Image Files(*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm)"));
    //QStringList inPixmap =QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,tr("Open Image"),"../AIC_Incoming_Images",tr ("Image Files(*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm)"));
    QString filename_1 =QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Image"),"../AIC_Incoming_Images",tr ("Image Files(*.png *.gif *.jpg *.tif *.xpm)"));
    QString filePath = QFileInfo(filename_1).fileName();
    QImage image_1(filename_1);



    QPixmap inPixmap =QPixmap::fromImage(image_1);

    //QPixmap inPixmap = screen->grabWindow( 0 );         // Keeping it in the image of the object QPixmap

    QByteArray inByteArray;                             // Create QByteArray object to save the image
    QBuffer inBuffer( &inByteArray );                   // Saving images produced through the buffer

    inBuffer.open( QIODevice::WriteOnly );              // Open buffer


    inPixmap.save( &inBuffer, "PNG" );                  // Write inPixmap in inByteArray

    // Write a screenshot of the database
    //db->insertIntoTable(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy_hh:mm:ss.png"), inByteArray);
    db->insertIntoTable(filePath, inByteArray);


    model->select();
}



void MainWindow::slotCurrentPic(QModelIndex index)
{
    QPixmap outPixmap = QPixmap(); // Create QPixmap, which will be placed in picLabel
    /* Taking the image data from the table as QByteArray and put them in QPixmap
     * */
    outPixmap.loadFromData(model->data(model->index(index.row(), 2)).toByteArray());
    ui->picLabel->setPixmap(outPixmap.scaled(1000,450));
    m_selectedId = model->data(model->index(index.row(), 0)).toInt();

}


void MainWindow::on_Delete_Button_clicked(QModelIndex index)
{

  db->removeRecord(id);

}
```

Comment: where is the QTableView?

Comment: i reupload the mainwindow.cpp  code .